# There was an error sending this message to your bot - Test in Web Chat

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a C# bot developed in Visual Studio which runs successfully on a bot emulator in desktop. This bot was published to Azure and again ran successfully in the bot emulator. I think this means that the app-ID and password of the bot are correct. However the same bot wouldn't work in web chat or in the "Test in Web Chat" window in Azure portal. It always replies with - couldn't send retry. Could someone please help me out?

Update: An inspection of "Issues" in Channel window gives the following error:- There was an error sending this message to your bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'd made a mistake in configuration. I had configured the messaging endpoint as an http URL. However bot configuration only seems to work with an https URL. Changing http to https fixed my problem. Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Comment: As I mentioned in my reply, the first thing you need to check is  **Messaging endpoint** that you configured.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

> the same bot wouldn't work in web chat or in the "Test in Web Chat" window in Azure portal. It always replies with - couldn't send retry.

To troubleshot the issue, you can try:

1. In [Settings blade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-manage-settings), please check the **Messaging endpoint** that you specified and make sure it is same as your using in the bot emulator.

   [image]
2. In the **Application Settings** blade, please check if you specify the correct **MicrosoftAppID** and **MicrosoftAppPassword** for your bot.
3. In **Channels** blade, please check the error message by clicking the "**Issues**" link for the affected channel.

   [image]
4. The bot application is hosted as Azure web app, try to [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) your code and check if the code is executed as expected.

Besides, if possible, you can try to [create a new bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart) on Azure portal, and publish your bot application to corresponding web application that you specified as messaging endpoint, and check if web chat works fine with that new bot.

Comment: An inspection of "Issues" in Channel window gives the following error:- There was an error sending this message to your bot.

Comment: You can check the http status code and detailed error message in response via F12 developer tools Network tab

Comment: Thanks did that and got-502 Bad Gateway {
  "error": {
    "code": "BotError",
    "message": "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"
  }
}

Comment: Similar issue is reported by AlavudeenRafiq in [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2201). And as dandriscoll said: *If your bot returns an HTTP 4xx or 5xx code, 502 will be sent back to web chat client.*

Answer (score 0):

This had me pulling my hair out - then I noticed some websocket errors in my browser's developer console - and after a browser restart it started working again!