# Bot works perfect in emulator but fails when deployed in test in webchat Send failed retry error

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I have a C# echo bot developed in Visual Studio as per Azure documentation which runs successfully on a bot emulator in desktop. This bot was deployed to Azure and it wouldn't work in web chat or in the "Test in Web Chat" window in Azure portal. It always replies with - couldn't send retry. Could someone please help me out?

This post [There was an error sending this message to your bot - Test in Web Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144699/there-was-an-error-sending-this-message-to-your-bot-test-in-web-chat) suggested to check the Messaging endpoint specified and make sure it is same as your using in the bot emulator.

However messaging endpoint in Azure is like https://webappname123.azurewebsites.net/api/messages but in emulator endpoint is a local host http://localhost:3978/api/messages . How can these two match?

Also when I went into channels issue is like "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound"

Is there any place where I could change endpoint URL?

I followed as it is process mentioned in Azure doc for building and deploying Echo bot

Comment: Has the issue resolved?

Comment: yes updating the appsettings.json solved the problem

Comment: Accepting / upvoting an answer serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" and upvote it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the correct  **Microsoft App ID** and **Microsoft App Password** in your appsettings.json ?

Your Azure **messaging endpoint** in azure configuration should be the **publicly accessible** endpoint, when you are debugging locally, the emulator can authenticate using those  **Microsoft App ID** and **Microsoft App Password** to reach your service.

When you deploy your solution your bot also authenticates using those credentials.

So make sure those credentials are correct and that your messaging endpoint "https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/messages " **is working** publicly

Comment: I added App ID and Password  in appsettings.json and deployed solution in Azure but still am getting same error messgae not sent retry.
After updating appsettings.json, now my bot emulator is also not running. please advise..

Comment: What is your messaging endpoint configured in the Bot channel registration ?

Comment: I just tried to POST and GET on https://webappyashwa.azurewebsites.net/api/messages and i get a 404 not found, make sure your service is actually up and running and that your bot is indeed listening to api/messages

Comment: check out these: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-bot-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-2019/ http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/1030/Creating-a-Hello-World-Bot-MS-Bot-Framework-V4-Preview-Edition

Answer (score 1):

When you publish your bot, there will be an option as below :

[image]

Select `Edit App Service Settings`.
Add the following details :

```
MicrosoftAppId : <xxxxx>
MicrosoftAppPassword : <xxxxx>
```

Click Apply, Ok.

Make sure you remove the `Microsoft App Id` and `Microsoft App Password` from `appsettings.json`, so that it works in bot emulator as well.

Now Publish the bot. It will work at both places.

Hope this is helpful.